# Sound stalling when executing some commands

Tags: sound, 20.04

I'm using 20.04. with no special anything but had the problem on the same machine days before before I upgraded from 18.04. 
When I'm working in my terminal and I execute some commands the sound skips or stalls for a second. This also happens when I'm connected to remote servers via SSH I think an for example switch to root, execute an rsync command and a lot of other commands. Even tab completion.
Only potential bad thing I see in dmesg is this.

```
[ 1877.835826] git[10446]: segfault at 0 ip 0000557bc9604dcc sp 00007ffe48232b00 error 4 in git[557bc9419000+220000]
```